# Is it possible to add a fragment for this hook wc_get_cart_remove_url()?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using that hook to remove an item in my cart page. I have a cart icon that has cart counter on it. I want to dynamically update the cart whenever a user deletes an item without reloading the page. After removing an item, the cart count only updates when the user reloads/refreshed the page.

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url(wc_get_cart_remove_url($cart_item_key)) ?>">
```

Comment: You need ajax for that. Share what you have tried so far. There are examples here and on the web how to make it.